# R: alignment numbers at risk in kaplan meier plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the jskm package to plot Kaplan Meier curves with numbers at risk table, but I cannot find a way to get the numbers at risk aligned with the ticks on the x-axis (It should be moved a little to the left). The `jskm` function doesn't seem to have an option for it. Can I use `ggplot` in some way for this?

```
library(survival)
library(jskm)
data(colon)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~rx, data=colon)
jskm(fit, timeby=500, table = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to your question (you'll probably need to reach out to the developers of `jskm` to fix the issue) - but if you use `survminer` package, it gives a correct alignment:

```
library(survminer)
data(colon)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~rx, data=colon)
ggsurvplot(fit, break.time.by=500, risk.table = T)
```

[image: Plot from survminer]

UPD. To remove the lower axis, you can replace corresponding elements with `element_blank`:

```
p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, break.time.by=500, risk.table = T)
p1$table$theme$axis.title.x <- element_blank()
p1$table$theme$axis.line.x <- element_blank()
p1$table$theme$axis.text.x <- element_blank()
p1$table$theme$axis.ticks.x <- element_blank()
p1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Works like a charm. Now the only issue is that I have 2 time axes. Is it possible to show only the numbers at risk without additional timeline and without the horizontal and vertical bloack lines surrounding it?

Comment: see the update. Let me know if it's what you needed